# Dynamic routes in next.js and query params

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

in my app I am using dyanmic routes in my nextjs app for a results page. You get to the results page from the product search page where there is a form for products. The form sends the search terms as a URL string query to the results page. Hence the results page URL is of the form:
results?lon=-0.130464&lat=51.518431&dist=20&product=12345

In my next pages folder I have a dynamic file called [results].tsx, and the files includes a getserversideprops function:

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuth({
  redirectTo: "/",
  async getServerSideProps(ctx, supabase) {
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    const { query } = ctx;

//more code that fetches likesData from supabase
```

the query object is then passed a props to the page:

```
function Results({ user, likesData, query }) {
  
  const queryTerms = query.tags;

  const filteredValues = tags.filter((val) =>
    Object.keys(val).some((key) => queryTerms.includes(key))
  );
```

I need to do some logic on the query and then make a client side call to the database. This all works fine, but I get an error warning during compile and build for the /results route. I think this is because the /results page on its own doesn't exist. Is there a special way to name the dynamic file in square brackets so that it only includes routes that include query params?

UPDATE: it's quite a strange error - it is actually thrown when a GET request is made to http://192.168.1.108:3000/favicon.ico, with the error message:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages/[results].tsx (22:46) @ eval

  20 | 
  21 | const filteredValues = tags.filter((val) =>
> 22 |   Object.keys(val).some((key) => queryTerms.includes(key))
     |                                            ^
  23 | );
  24 | 
  25 | // return only values from filteredValues
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: just added an update above

Comment: ah duh me - I think the issue is due the the [results].tsx file being in the root folder so wasn't configured to handle requests to /favicon.ico